# alias for watch command gets stopped?

Tags: bash, alias, watch

I create this alias, so that aliases get expanded in the watch statement.

```
> alias w='watch -x bash -i -c'
> alias k=kubectl
```

I execute it:

```
> w 'k get pods; echo; k get svc'
```

After two seconds I see:

```
[2]+  Stopped                 watch -x bash -i -c 'k get pods; echo; k get svc'
```

And the watch command stopped.

Why does the watch command get stopped?

Version: Bash 5.1.16. Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Also I don't think it's the alias that stops, it's the `watch` command itself. I'd recommend skipping the aliases until you get `watch` command working, just to follow KISS principle.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with your command:

1. `bash -i` starts an interactive shell session, and you can't use `watch` with an interactive command. This is why you get the "Stopped" message. If you had run this from a `zsh` shell, it would additionally have said `suspended (tty output)`.
2. Aliases are not inherited by child processes, which means that your `k` alias in your shell won't be visible inside the shell you "watch".

Instead:

```bash
watch -x bash -c 'kubectl get pods; echo; kubectl get svc'
```

or,

```bash
watch 'kubectl get pods; echo; kubectl get svc'
```

This does not run an interactive `bash` shell with `watch`, and it does not try to use an alias that isn't defined.

If your point with running an interactive shell is to have aliases expanded, then use `bash` with its `expand_aliases` shell option instead:

```bash
watch -x bash -O expand_aliases -c $'alias k=kubectl\nk get pods; echo; k get svc'
```

Note that I have to define the alias inside the inline script and that I also have to insert a literal newline after the alias definition (you can't use an alias on the same line that you define it on). I do this by letting the command string be a C string (`$'...'`) and then adding the newline with `\n`. You could also insert a literal newline in the command string like this:

```bash
watch -x bash -O expand_aliases -c 'alias k=kubectl
k get pods; echo; k get svc'
```